# Tensorflow 2.3 and libcublas.so.10

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to official documentation, in Tensorflow 2.3 [CUDA 10.1 is supported](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

I have Ubuntu 20.04, GPU onboard, CUDA 10.1 and CUDNN 7.6

I am getting the error when start using Tensorflow (2.3):
**Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10';
dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64**

After some hours of investigations, it turned out that CUBLAS packaging changed in CUDA 10.1 to be **outside** of the toolkit installation path

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
```

See here :
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cublas-for-10-1-is-missing/71015/16

In my case I searched with

```
sudo find /usr -name libcublas*
```

and founded :

```
            /usr/share/doc/libcublas-dev
            /usr/share/doc/libcublas10
            /usr/local/cuda-10.1/doc/man/man7/libcublas.so.7
            /usr/local/cuda-10.1/doc/man/man7/libcublas.7
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.10.2.2.214
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.10.2.2.214
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs/libcublasLt.so
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs/libcublas.so
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.10
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_static.a
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt_static.a
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.10
            /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so
```

Then, following some suggestions for workarounds using symlink (founded in the nvdia site), I created a symlink for the files above founded, to the :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so.10
```

Even after the symlinks, the error persists:

**Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64**

with my `nano ~/.profile` containing :

```
# set PATH for cuda 10.1 installation
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi
```

I wanted also to try and take manually the files from the toolkit available in the *cuda_10.1.168_418.67_linux.run* file as suggested [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cublas-for-10-1-is-missing/71015/16)  but have founded that the suggested command does not work.I adjusted to command :

```
sh cuda_10.1.168_418.67_linux.run --extract=/extracted
```

which goes KO when finalizing with a message ..
**Failed to verify gcc version. See log at /tmp/cuda-installer.log for details.**

If only that extraction could work, maybe a manual copy of the files saves the full headache.

It seems that this cublas step is not documented in Tensorflow official documentation for installing with CUDA 10.1

Any idea ?

Comment: You have CUDA 10.2 loaded/installed. You **cannot** use that as a replacement for CUDA 10.1 which your TF install is expecting.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that is what one could suspect, but 10.2 folders are there just because this comes with 10.1: I never ever installed 10.2, and it's just the way Nvidia decided to install cublas from 10.1.

the command 
nvcc --version

is confirming :
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, solved thank to your question. I used the symlink aproach but adding an extra one for `libcublasLt.so.10`.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so.10
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublasLt.so.10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so.10
```

these are not appropriate to resolve this problem.
we should re-install packages related with `libcublas` for **CUDA 10.1**.

I've re-installed with `apt`.

- my env. based on CUDA repos by NVIDIA.

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall libcublas10=10.2.1.243-1 libcublas-dev=10.2.1.243-1
```

then `libcublas` libraries are moved into `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/`.

and preventing that appear upgradable candidate.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold libcublas10
$ sudo apt-mark hold libcublas-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Add path of CUDA 10.2 in bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

This should be sufficient.